# Rails - How to assign temporary id of a post to reference images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple blog site built on rails. I have a `Post` model and `Picture` model.

A `Post` `has_many` `pictures` and

A `Picture` `belongs_to` `post`

**Below is what I want to achieve -**

1. When I start to create new post, I will provide a link in the form that opens up a new window where I can upload multiple reference images with some `name` field as well.
2. Then I will use a macro string in my post body like `##IMG_<image-name>##`.
3. I will dynamically create a new `<img>` tag to display relevant images, while the user is still creating the post.

**My Problems -**

1. As you know, during the time of post creation, I will not have a post_id.
2. Then how do I relate the reference_images being uploaded to a particular post?
3. Can I somehow assign a temporary-id to the post as soon as I enter create page and then after I save the post, anyway rails will takeover?

Hope you got where I am stuck. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: image page is different from post creation?

Comment: If you're using Paperclip, this might help: [Rails Paperclip with model association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3261417/260411).

Comment: After opening the new window, upload the photos and save them without adding `post_id`. Now save the post with small tweak in your create action. In your create action, After `@post.save post_params`, assign all the photos having no `id` to the current post. `Photo.where(id: nil).each {|photo| photo.post_id = @post.id}`

Comment: Let me know if above is not working

Comment: You can make the `belongs_to` association in Picture optional and assign it later. Or you can use nested attributes.

Comment: @AkashPinnaka - what if there are multiple users using the system at the same time? Then the first user to finish his post will "claim" the images the belonging to the other users.

Comment: @max Oh if it has multiple users, then we should do differently. We have to save the post first and then images it seems.

Comment: I think its a pretty good assumption that your application should work for more than one simultaneous user @AkashPinnaka

Comment: Yes. It actually is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172753/discussion-between-akash-pinnaka-and-max).

Comment: How about saving the post without details(title, content) and assigning the images to the currently saved post when clicked on **save images** button in another window? And again if he click on submit the post, it updates(PUT) the attributes from nil to the form fields content

Comment: @Arunko Did it work? Or you have any better solution?

Comment: @max What do you say about the above approach?

Comment: Thank you all guys. I achieved it in a hacky way.

1. I provided a separate API for uploding images to Cloudinary using paperclip.

2. The callback of the paperclip upload will give me the remote URL of the image uploaded. I responded the API request with this URL.

3. I used the URL from response to directly embed the <img> tag into the post body instead of keeping them as reference images.

Comment: @AkashPinnaka - Your idea of saving a post without any details would work. But the overhead is, we will end up saving all the incomplete posts which user might have intended to discard.

Comment: @Arunko We can delete the post along with images when user discarded. But the IDs unnecessarily increases. Your idea of getting remote url is actually great. But what if we want to save in the disk space of our own server?

Comment: @AkashPinnaka - Not only IDs increase, but we also will not know if the user has discraded the post. Because, I do not have any button that says `discard`. If user navigates out of create_post page without saving, it means he has chosen to discard. -------- If we like to save in our own server, even then same logic holds true. We would then respond with a image URL of our domain, instead of cloudinary's.

Comment: Ok cool idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate all the responses you have given. But I had to achieve this is another hacky way for my needs -

**HTML**

- I provided a `<input type="file" id="refImg" onchange="javascript: uploadImage(this);">`.
- After the user has selected the required image, the `uploadImage()` funtion would create a dynamic form and do an AJAX POST to a distinct API. `http://example.com/uploadImage`

**Rails**

- In rails controller `referenceImages#uploadImage`, I used paperclip to upload the image to cloudinary. The cloudinary upload call will return back with the image URL, if the upload is successful.
- I responded with this URL in the JSON format.

**JS**

- In javascript function `uploadImage()`, in the success function of ajax call, I parsed the URL from the response and dynamically created a `<img src="parsed_image_url">` tag and appended it to the current cursor position of post body.